# Angular (Ionic) app build on Heroku - Error: ENOENT

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, heroku, build

I am trying to deploy my Angular app to the Heroku, but I still get the error in the Heroku console:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/dist/index.html'
```

Here is my `server.js` file

```js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/dist"));

app.get("/*", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "dist", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

I also tried to put `appName` instead of `dist`, but didn't work.

I also removed `/dist` from `.gitignore`

I set `"postinstall": "ng build --aot --prod"` and `"start": "node server.js"` scripts in `package.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in the name of the file - Ionic build file is called /www, not /dist.